# Can Apple Mac OS runs on virtual machine in Windows as build host with Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I want to develop an iOS mobile app using Xamarin in Windows. Can Apple Mac OS run on a virtual machine in Windows, rather than run on a separate physical machine as build host? 
 If possible, any link to the setup would be appreciated, for running Virtualbox, Windows 7, Mac OS.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/

Comment: I dont know if it is possible but I think it is forbidden by license to use OSX on other then Apple devices,

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff, I have updated my question. But I don't understand the last part of your comment. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Apple's license forbids running OS X in a VM on non-Apple hardware.

Comment: Yes It can
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z3S1zDseuY8)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Short answer: **Yes it can**

Long answer:

As it's been noted in the comments above, you can **only** legally (wrt license) run a OSX VM on Apple hardware.

IOW if you have a Mac Book Pro (or any Apple hardware) running Windows and a VM running OSX **you're fine**, both technically and license wise. OTOH you're **not** fine to use any other (non-Apple) computer brand running Windows and virtualize OSX.

The setup itself will be identical, from Xamarin's tools perpectives (the above linked documents still applies). It will be two computers (one real, one virtual) communicating with each others thru the (virtual) network.

Comment: For someone needing a translator.  "IOW" - In Other Words.  "OTOH" - On The Other Hand.

Answer (score 17):

As stated above, it is not in Apple's terms of agreement to run OSX on anything but an Apple product so you shouldn't do it.

Although if for some educational reason you were to install OS X Yosemite (["Hackintosh"](http://www.macbreaker.com/2015/01/virtualbox-yosemite-zone.html) ) inside of Virtual Box on Windows, set the Network adapter to "[Bridged Adapter](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/diy-it-guy/using-virtualbox-vms-on-your-networks-subnet/)" and get the Xamarin build host installed and running (as well as Xcode from the [App Store](http://www.tonymacx86.com/yosemite-desktop-support/145283-my-hackintosh-not-recognized-app-store-after-yosemite-upgrade.html)), then it might be possible to connect from Visual Studios.  But as stated, you shouldn't do it ;)