# Is it possible to build xamarin.ios applications on mac host for vs2015 with free license?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xamarin

I installed OS X Yosemite ("Hackintosh" ) inside of Virtual Box on Windows, set the Network adapter to "Bridged Adapter" and get the Xamarin build host installed and running (as well as Xcode from the App Store), paired it up on VS2015, got it to the point of building and then it got stuck on the error message:

> 1>C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\iOS\Xamarin.iOS.Common.targets(524,3): error :
>   No installed provisioning profiles match the installed iOS code
>   signing keys.

Started investigating into this, followed some articles where it should come to Xcode Account. I entered my Apple Id, then checked created certificates, but it never gets into download of provisioning profiles.

I dont intend to publish I only want to check Xamarin on the apple Iphone simulator, so can I get around to being able to do this without enrolling for paid apple developer program?

Comment: This site is for programming questions, not legal advice. We are not here to interpret software licenses for you.

Comment: @MarcB there is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090796/can-apple-mac-os-runs-on-virtual-machine-in-windows-as-build-host-with-xamarin-i, but it doesnt answer how to do it with free license. The question is about building applications, not legal advice

Comment: You do not need a provisioning profile to run on a Simulator, only a device. You will want to make sure you have your iOS project set as startup and that you select iPhoneSimulator as your build started and select one form the debug menu.

Comment: @JamesMontemagno reinstalling Xamarin did a trick for me, there were no devices listed in Run menu too, now it runs ok, without any problems...

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create a app ID before you can create a provisioning profile.
You can do that on developer.apple.com/ios