# How to simulate native iOS app on Windows for UI tests?

Tags: xamarin.ios

Is there a way to emulate/simulate a native iOS app on Windows in order to identify the elements and properties for UI tests?
I have: .ipa file, source code, visual studio, Win-PC, iPhone but no Mac to build and simulate the app which is written using Xamarin.iOS.

I am not looking for online platforms like Browserstack, Saucelabs, AppCenter or similar. I am familiar with those options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Apple Mac OS runs on virtual machine in Windows as build host with Xamarin.iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090796/can-apple-mac-os-runs-on-virtual-machine-in-windows-as-build-host-with-xamarin-i)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware it is only possible to build iOS applications using a Mac build host. However, I am familiar with other people using a virtual machine to simulate a MacOS. This link could be considered a duplicate to your question and it seems to have been answered succinctly. As is noted in other threads, be careful with the certain legality of this approach.
[Can Apple Mac OS runs on virtual machine in Windows as build host with Xamarin.iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27090796/can-apple-mac-os-runs-on-virtual-machine-in-windows-as-build-host-with-xamarin-i)