# Do I need a Mac to build iOS Xamarin apps with Visual Studio 2017 Pro?

Tags: ios, visual-studio, deployment, xamarin.ios

According to this post [Xamarin Visual Studio IOS Development Without a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508487/xamarin-visual-studio-ios-development-without-a-mac) the answer is yes, but this is 3 years ago ... is it still the case under Visual Studio 2017 Pro?

This answer isn't in the above link because those answers are 3+ years old.

Comment: Yes. No change.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Visual Studio IOS Development Without a Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508487/xamarin-visual-studio-ios-development-without-a-mac)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. If you use Visual Studio 2017 for Mac, the answer is no :)

Comment: Well, obviously I'll still need a Mac to run VS2017 for Mac. :)