# Xamarin ios app without mac machine

Tags: xamarin.ios

I have downloaded xamarin with visual studio 2017 on windows, but don't have mac machine as a mac agent , I have iphone mobile to using in testing

Is there any way to build and test Xamarin  ios app on iphone without pay mac machine . and if there is way, does it allow me to upload the app to apple store without mac machine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin Visual Studio IOS Development Without a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508487/xamarin-visual-studio-ios-development-without-a-mac)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've purchased a laptop already

Answer (score 2):

You need a Mac for Xamarin development unfortunately. One way to do is to rent a virtual mac and do your development over there. But depending on your connection it can be very slow https://www.macincloud.com/.

For upload, if you can somehow get the .ipa file, you can use website like http://www.connectuploader.com to help you upload your app to the app store.