# Signing Xamarin.iOS Certificate in Visual Studio Windows Error

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

am trying to add an iOS certificate in Visual Studio 2019 but am getting this error
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGxKd.png)

What might be the issue? NB: I don't have a MacBook, I only have an Apple developer account and iPhone

Comment: You need either a mac or mac on vm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Visual Studio IOS Development Without a Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508487/xamarin-visual-studio-ios-development-without-a-mac)

Answer (score 0):

You need a mac to make a releasable build (for testflight or app store submission). See [Xamarin Hot Restart - Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart#limitations). This includes doing any "signing".

You should be able to develop and debug on your iPhone - but you can't make it available to anyone else, without a Mac. If you haven't yet succeeded in running it on your attached iPhone, check whether you followed all the [Hot Restart instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart). Or for another discussion of steps, try [these non-official instructions](https://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/ios-dev-no-mac/).

Comment: [Hot Restart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/deploy-test/hot-restart) enables we to test without mac , but in this way it has lots of limitation . Mac is required for fully developing iOS , @cedric shimuli you need a mac first and  then develop xamairn.iOS.

Comment: Meaning even for Hot Restart I need a mac?

Comment: @cedricshimuli - I've updated my answer, with a more accurate explanation of what you can and can't do. And links to two places with steps to follow, if you haven't yet succeeded in running Hot Restart at all on your iPhone.

Comment: @cedric shimuli Hot Restart does not need mac, but it has lots of limitation , it is not recommended. For signing in Xamarin.iOS , you have to get a mac first.